# Is there some way to stop XCode from showing errors and prompts while I type the code?

Tags: xcode

Isn't there some way by which I get to know the errors only after I have compiled the program? I don't want to XCode to prompt me for semi colons as I am a student and want to learn how to do it the right way.

Comment: Switch off "Show Live Issues" in the General preferences.

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really. I was earlier considering even shifting to Windows for this.

Answer (score 3):

### Xcode 12.2 - 2022

1. Open Xcode preferences (**command + ,**)
2. Open **General** tab
3. Switch off **Show live issues**

[image: make show live issues off]